# Who is Jeff-Kun? Is there any canonical references about him besides what is shown in the Anime?

Tags: magic-users-club

Jeff-kun is both the stuffed bear charm and the mysterious magician / <s>pen-pal / mentor of Sae</s> (supposedly the stuffed bear was given to Sae by him).

EDIT: I misplaced Jeff with Miki-senpai.

He is shown as a silhouette in the end of S2, but still remains shrouded in mystery.

The other kids don't even register Jeff-kun as a distinct entity. They just assume Sae is taking to the toy.

Is the information above correct? Is there any other source as to who Jeff-kun really is?